# How can I use an operator In the where clause to compare the results returned from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause, operator-keyword, comparison-operators

I would like to use a greater than operator to find the students in the outer query that have a greater salary than the students in the subquery.

I tried using a `>` the operator in the where clause, however, this approach doesn't work as the subquery returns more than a row.

How can I use an operator in the where clause to compare the records from the outer query to the many rows returned from the subquery in order to find the students in the outer query with a higher salary than the students in the subquery?

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENTS AS S INNER JOIN PACKAGES AS P
ON S.ID = P.ID
WHERE P.SALARY > (SELECT P.SALARY
                  FROM FRIENDS AS F INNER JOIN PACKAGES AS P
                  ON F.FRIEND_ID = P.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a workaround. You could add an outer query with the max value of the subquery records and compare with that single value.

> Note that this solution only include all the  student on the outer
> query that has the greater salary than the max value of the subquery.

Try:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM STUDENTS AS S 
INNER JOIN PACKAGES AS PON S.ID = P.ID
WHERE P.SALARY > (  
                  SELECT MAX(t1.P.SALARY)   
                  FROM (  
                        SELECT P.SALARY
                         FROM FRIENDS AS F INNER JOIN PACKAGES AS P ON F.FRIEND_ID = P.ID
                       ) as t1
                 );
```